# Qt's mouse event

Tags: c++, qt

I have a old project written in Qt4, where mouse event are used everywhere.
Now I hope to move this project to touch screen.
Instead of add in gesture event everywhere, is there a simple solution that could some how map the gesture into a mouse event? So that I could reuse many codes.

Comment: You can install event filter and proxy mouse events.

Comment: Could you give more hint like a Link or some Docs or examples?

Comment: Could you use google? Use search requests like "qt install event filter". Or you can clarify your questions.